# Specifying that a given shortopt can accept an optional argument, C

Tags: c, getopt, command-line-arguments

How do you specify that a short-option can accept an optional_argument in `getopt`.

As far as I can tell, GNU's getopt library for C only supports required-arguments for short-options by adding a `:` after a given option.

Example:

```
static const char* short_opts = "s:evlh";
```

How do I specify that `s` accepts arguments, but doesn't require them?

I know how to do this in Ruby, but I've never been able to figure out how to do it in C--I've reviewed the GNU documentation for getopt several times, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt):

> If an option character is followed by two colons (‘::’), its argument is optional; this is a GNU extension.

Comment: thanks, I had a suspiscion that this was the case, but for some reason I thought that I was getting it wrong or something like that...